# Assign a function to a change in QcomboBox

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have tried to call a function when there has been a change in the QcomboBox. When the comboBox is changed it will update the xAxis on a graph. Is there a way to call a function when a different item is selected from the comboBox?

```
def updateGraph():
    print("update graph")

proxy = QtGui.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
xAxis = QtGui.QComboBox()
proxy.setWidget(xAxis)
xAxis.currentIndexChanged().connect(updateGraph)
```

Error that is currently produced:

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
xAxis.currentIndexChanged().connect(updateGraph)
```

to

```
xAxis.currentIndexChanged.connect(updateGraph)
```

With the parentheses in front of `currentIndexChanged` you are actually calling the signal, when you really want to access the signal's `connect` method.